# How to get another specified attribute using grouping by from LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I'm using LINQ to XML.

This is the line which I'm having problems:

```
var objectives = (from c in xdoc.Descendents("Condition")
                  group c by (int)c.Attribute("ObjectiveID") into k
                  select k).ToDictionary(e=> e.Key, // HERE I MUST PUT ANOTHER ATTRIBUTE FROM c)
```

Where I put the comment, I need to get another attribute (c.Attribute("Objective")). But I can't access to c properties and get that one.

Comment: first of all give some example of xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A grouping may contain more than one item per group. A dictionary on the other hand can only contain one value for each key. You probably want [`ToLookup()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549211.aspx) which does allow an enumeration of values for each key:

```
var objectives = (from c in xdoc.Descendents("Condition")
                  group c by (int)c.Attribute("ObjectiveID") into k
                  select k).ToLookup(e=> e.Key, e => e.Select( x=> x.Objective));
```

If you *do* want to use a dictionary you can just pick i.e. the first item of each grouping:

```
var objectives = (from c in xdoc.Descendents("Condition")
                  group c by (int)c.Attribute("ObjectiveID") into k
                  select k).ToDictionary(e=> e.Key, e => e.First().Objective));
```